# Vim: Close All Buffers But This One

Tags: vim

How can I close all buffers in Vim except the one I am currently editing?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You could use this script from vim.org:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1071

Just put it to your `.vim/plugin` directory and then use `:BufOnly` command to close all buffers but the active one. You could also map it elsewhere you like in your `.vimrc`.

Source on Github (via vim-scripts mirror): https://github.com/vim-scripts/BufOnly.vim/blob/master/plugin/BufOnly.vim

Answer (score 296):

I was able to do this pretty easily like this:

```
:%bd|e#
```

Comment: This is a nice answer. It makes BufOnly feel a bit overkill (I mean, a whole plugin?) unless you're using the argument passing feature of BufOnly. All I ever want to really do is `:%bd|e#`

Comment: This looks pretty nice to me! Care to elaborate on how it works?

Comment: @jorgeh        
`%bd` = delete all buffers. `e#` = open the last buffer for editing. The pipe in between just does one command after another.

Comment: Cool, thanks. So what happens if there are unsaved changes in the current buffer? I see @iamnotsam proposed a very similar solution but prefixing it with `w|`, to save the buffer before closing it. I guess a comment in this regard could help other in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you - I didn't think about that. I guess I'm such a save stickler I never ran into that.

Comment: If only it could be aliassed as `bda[ll]` - would make for some good buffer clearing porn :D

Comment: how does that work? bd --> buffer destroy. what's the | for ? and e and #   ?

Comment: @アレックス `%bd` = delete all buffers. `e#` = open the last buffer for editing. The pipe in between just does one command after another.

Comment: Doesn't that leave an extra buffer open? When you `%bd` you're going to end up with a `[No Name]` buffer, which will be around after you `e#`

Comment: @Jared I just checked and it looks like you're right. `%bd` does indeed leave a `[No Name]` buffer behind. Is it possible to have vim open with no buffers?

Comment: @OldTimeGuitarGuy no that is not possible, but it is possible to put vim into a state where only one buffer remains. Although I'm not sure it's possible with a one liner. mynyml's solution has the desirable effect, I think.

Comment: @Jared You can use `%bd|e#|bd#` to delete the `[No Name]` buffer that gets created.

Comment: Wonderful. Then here you have the only thing I ever used the BufOnly plugin for, distilled to a single command: `command! BufOnly silent! execute "%bd|e#|bd#"`

Comment: I map it to the key like this but it show the syntax error: `map <leader>o :%bd|e#<cr>` where is the mistake?

Comment: @Finn you need to escape `|`: `map <leader>o :%bd\|e#<cr>`

Comment: Once I have a Preserve function to keep my cursor position I have created this: `command! BufOnly silent! call Preserve("exec '%bd|e#|bd#'")`

Comment: This answer is peak vim lol. Saying something is easy while to most people is actually just random symbols.

Answer (score 221):

Try this

```
bufdo bd
```

bufdo runs command for all buffers

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Run_a_command_in_multiple_buffers

Comment: This doesn't close the NERDTree buffer.

Comment: NERDTree is closed if focus is in nerd tree panel

Comment: You might want to close NERDTree before doing this to prevent the `bd` command close the vim itself; `nnoremap <silent> <leader>c :NERDTreeClose<bar>bufdo bd<CR>`.

Comment: The documentation warns that the argument to [`:bufdo`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:bufdo) ‘must not delete buffers or add buffers to the buffer list’. So if this solution works, it works by accident …  and it often doesn’t work for me (switches to a different buffer).

Comment: This closes all buffers for me, which is not what the questions asks. (MacVim version 8.0.1207)

Comment: try :only  for this

Comment: This command closes all the buffers. How can I leave the current one open?

Comment: @nick-s , try to use :only for this

Comment: @gayavat I just tried `:only`. It does not close the buffer, unless you have set `hidden`.

Answer (score 61):

If you don´t care the current one, is more simple to do something like (no script needing):

```
1,100bd
```

Comment: It will close nerdtree buffer as well.

Comment: I faced some problems using this command when NERDTree is enabled. I recomment using the BufOnly.vim plugin as mentioned by @VoY .

Comment: I made the following mapping which accounts for deleting the NERDTree buffer: `nnoremap <leader>bd :%bd | NERDTree<cr>
`

Comment: I used this for a long time, but now I get `E16: Invalid range` because some of the buffers in the range don't actually exist. It was ignoring that until recently.

Comment: @Jon Check `:ls` to see the largest buffer you actually have open, and set your range to that (i.e. if your highest buffer is 22, then `:1,22bd`). I got the same error until I did that.

Answer (score 60):

I do this

```
:w | %bd | e#
```

My favorite if I just want my current buffer open and close all others.

How it works: first write current buffer's changes, then close all open buffers, then reopen the buffer I was currently on. In Vim, the `|` chains the execution of commands together. If your buffer is up to date the above can be shortened to `:%bd | e#`

Comment: It mostly works fine. but sometimes `%` can't work as all selector. Could you guess anything?

Comment: @JinyoungKim (from [1]) In the ":%bd" command, the '%' range will be replaced with the starting and
ending line numbers in the current buffer. Instead of using '%' as the
range, you should specify numbers for the range. For example, to delete all
the buffers, you can use the command ":1,9999bd"
[1] http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/vimfaq2html3.pl#8.8

Comment: I just checked out the document. So then, '%' range rely on a number of current file lines?

Comment: Yes @JinyoungKim that is correct. I tried substituting % with a range but that yielded an error (:w | 1,999bd | e#) so as for now I do not know the best solution here. If you find one, please ping me.

Comment: I found built-in function `bufnr("$")` that returns last buffer number. but I have no idea to interpolate to string when I use like this `:1,bufnr("$")bd`. Maybe.. best solution would be `:1,9999bd`.

Comment: `:help :bd` shows `:%bdelete       " delete all buffers`. So `%` is exactly what you want. I use a variant of your solution: `:%bd<CR><C-O>:bd#<CR>` This will delete all buffers, then use `<C-O>` to get restore the position in the current file, then `:bd#` to remove the unamed buffer. This closes all buffers and leaves you in the same location in the file.

Answer (score 28):

Building on juananruiz's answer.

Make a small change in the buffer you want to keep, then

`:1,1000bd`

The command `bd` (buffer delete) will not delete any buffers with unsaved changes. This way you can keep the current (changed) file in the buffer list.

Edit: Please notice that this will also delete your NERDTreeBuffer. You can get it back with :NERDTree

Comment: Perfect, short and simple! :)

Comment: :%bd is actually "all" instead 1-1000.

Comment: Does this rely on `set nohidden` to be set?

Comment: This is the best answer. Even works when you want to keep more than one buffer.

Comment: Thi should be the accepted answer. No command sequence to memorize, and retains the editing history of the buffer(s) you want to keep. As easy as it gets, wich I could upvote it more :)

Answer (score 21):

Here's what I do. So I like to keep my cursor position after removing all buffers and most of the solutions above just ignores this fact. I also think remapping the command is better than typing it so Here I use `<leader>bd` to remove all buffers and jump back to my original cursor position.

```
noremap <leader>bd :%bd\|e#\|bd#<cr>\|'"
```

`%bd` = delete all buffers.

`e#` = open the last buffer for editing (Which Is the buffer I'm working on).

`bd#` to delete the [No Name] buffer that gets created when you use `%bd`.

The pipe in between just does one command after another. You've gotta escape it though using `\|`

`'"` = keep my cursor position.

Answer (score 20):

I put this in my .vimrc file

```
nnoremap <leader>ca :w <bar> %bd <bar> e# <bar> bd# <CR>
```

then your `leader + ca` (close all) close all the buffers except the current one.

What it does is

:w - save current buffer

%bd - close all the buffers

e# - open last edited file

bd# - close the unnamed buffer

Comment: Love it, tweaked slightly and added to my config: `nnoremap <silent> <leader>bo :w <bar> %bd <bar> e# <bar> bd# <CR><CR>`

Comment: I would suggest changing `:w ...` for `:up ...` (update) only writes if the current file has changed.

Answer (score 17):

**Note**: As mentioned in the comments, this closes **windows** and **not buffers**.

By using

```
:on[ly][!]
```

and

```
:h only
```

Comment: Still useful, as people may well Googling for the wrong term, and will find this. So thanks to both of you. :)

Comment: @archgoon yeah, but should be specified in the answer.

Comment: You can also use `C-W o` to achieve this

Answer (score 10):

Closing all open buffers:

```
silent! execute "1,".bufnr("$")."bd"
```

Closing all open buffers **except for the current one**:

```
function! CloseAllBuffersButCurrent()
  let curr = bufnr("%")
  let last = bufnr("$")

  if curr > 1    | silent! execute "1,".(curr-1)."bd"     | endif
  if curr < last | silent! execute (curr+1).",".last."bd" | endif
endfunction
```

Add this function to `.vimrc` and call it using `:call CloseAllBuffersButCurrent()`.

Convenience map:

```
nmap <Leader>\c :call CloseAllBuffersButCurrent()<CR>
```

Comment: I noticed that when resuming vim sessions, which does restore buffers, I wasn't able to remove buffers anymore using the above. Instead, I had to use `:%bd|e#|bd#`

Comment: Best solution. I added a command to reopen NERDTree `nmap <Leader>\c :call CloseAllBuffersButCurrent()<CR>:NERDTree<CR>`

Answer (score 9):

There's a **plugin** that does exactly this and a bit more!

Check out **[close-buffers.vim](https://github.com/Asheq/close-buffers.vim)**

Comment: Absolutely fantastic plugin! Having tried the other options (remappings) I highly recommend this plugin.

Answer (score 7):

```
:%bd then Ctrl-o
```

:%bd to delete all buffers

Ctrl-o to jump back to the last buffer, which would be the "This One" you were referring to.

Comment: This will leave 2 buffers actually. The "last buffer" and an empty one.

Answer (score 2):

so this is an old question but it helped me get some ideas for my project. in order to close all buffers but the one you are currently using, use;

`map <leader>o :execute "%bd\|e#"<CR>`

Answer (score 1):

- The answer with highest votes will reopen the buffer, it will lose the current line we are working on.
- Close then reopen will induce a flush on screen

```
function! CloseOtherBuffer()
    let l:bufnr = bufnr()
    execute "only"
    for buffer in getbufinfo()
        if !buffer.listed
            continue
        endif
        if buffer.bufnr == l:bufnr
            continue
        else
            if buffer.changed
                echo buffer.name . " has changed, save first"
                continue
            endif
            let l:cmd = "bdelete " . buffer.bufnr
            execute l:cmd
        endif
    endfor
endfunction

let mapleader = ','
nnoremap <leader>o :call CloseOtherBuffer()<CR>
```

Previous code will take effect when you are on the target buffer and press , + o. It will close all other buffers except current one.

It iterates all the buffers and close all the buffer number which is not equal to current buffer number.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `lua` function that does this. Added benefit is that the current buffer doesn't get closed at all so the cursor remains in the same position:

```lua
CloseAllButCurrent = function()
  local current_buf = vim.fn.bufnr()
  local current_win = vim.fn.win_getid()
  local bufs = vim.fn.getbufinfo({buflisted = 1})
  for _, buf in ipairs(bufs) do
    if buf.bufnr ~= current_buf then
      vim.cmd("silent! bdelete " .. buf.bufnr)
    end
  end
  vim.fn.win_gotoid(current_win)
end
```

And then map it with something like:

```lua
vim.keymap.set(
  "n",
  '<leader>aq',
  function() CloseAllButCurrent() end,
  {silent = true, desc = "Close all other buffers except current one." }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

With lua as suggested [here](https://neovim.discourse.group/t/delete-all-but-current-buffer/3953)

This works quite well for me

```lua
local function closeAllBuffersButCurrentOne()
    local bufs = vim.api.nvim_list_bufs()
    local current_buf = vim.api.nvim_get_current_buf()
    for _, i in ipairs(bufs) do
        if i ~= current_buf then
            vim.api.nvim_buf_delete(i, {})
        end
    end
end
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>Q', closeAllBuffersButCurrentOne)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just:

```
ctrl-w o
```

(thanks to https://thoughtbot.com/blog/vim-splits-move-faster-and-more-naturally)

Comment: This closes windows, not buffers.

Answer (score 0):

I like `1,100bd` ([suggested by juananruiz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21191487/3982001)) which seems to work for me.

I added a `quit!` to my mapping to give me

```
nnoremap <leader>bd :1,100bd<CR>
nnoremap <leader>bdq :1,100bd<CR>:q!<CR>
```

This kills all the buffers and shuts down Vim, which is what I was looking for mostly.

Comment: There's really no reason for you to have the `bdq` mapping that closes all buffers and exits vim with `:q!`, when instead you can just use `:qa!`. Unless I'm overlooking something

Answer (score 0):

I combined [Alejandro's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545275/vim-close-all-buffers-but-this-one#comment79869898_34050776) with [badteeth's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545275/vim-close-all-buffers-but-this-one#comment86214068_42071865):

```
command! Bonly silent execute "%bd|norm <C-O>"
```

- The `norm <C-O>` jumps to the last position in the jump list, which means where the cursor was before the `%bd`.
- I used `silent` instead of `silent!`.  That way, if any open buffers are modified, Vim prints an error message so I know what happened.  The modified buffers stay open in my tests.

<sub>Unrelated: this is my 500th answer!</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
nnoremap <leader>x :execute '%bdelete\|edit #\|normal `"'\|bdelete#<CR>
```

- Close all buffers (side-effect creates new empty buffer)
- Open last buffer
- Jump to last edit position in buffer
- Delete empty buffer

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the solution of mynyml, here's the Lua version:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command("BufClose", function ()
  local current_buffer = vim.fn.bufnr("%")
  local last_buffer = vim.fn.bufnr("$")

  if current_buffer > 1 then
    vim.cmd("silent! " .. "1, " .. current_buffer - 1 .. "bd")
  end

  if current_buffer < last_buffer then
    vim.cmd("silent! " .. current_buffer + 1 .. "," .. last_buffer .. "bd")
  end
end, {
  nargs = 0,
})

-- now just
:BufClose
```