# Deleting all buffers except first one with one command

Tags: vim

I'm using the perlsupport plugin to do syntax checking on my code. When it does the syntax checking, it places the files with warnings and errors into buffers. Sometimes I want to quickly close out those other buffers except for the first one because it is the script I'm currently working in.

I've tried `2,:bd` and `2,$:bd` and `:bd 2 Quickfix\ List` and `:bd 2 [Quickfix\ List]` and other variations without success. Thanks.

I should add that I know I can list out the buffers, find the last buffer number and do something like `2,N:bd` but I'd rather have just one command I can turn into a shortcut.

Comment: `:2,999bd` ? From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545275/vim-close-all-buffers-but-this-one - possible duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a command that uses [`exec`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute) to build the correct `bd` command:

```
command! Bd exec '2,' . bufnr("$") . 'bd'
```

[`bufnr("$")`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#bufnr%28%29) is the number of the last buffer.

As a test:

```
:badd foo
:badd bar
:Bd
```

Gives:

```
2 buffers deleted
```